# application.js function removed after changing layout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, render

I'm using Rails 6.0.3.1 to create an app where the layout is changed when the new method is called this way:

```
def index
  @groups = Group.all
  render layout: 'application'
end

def new
  @group = current_user.groups.build
  render layout: 'without_sidebar'
end
```

my /app/javascript/packs/application.js is having this function inside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

After inspecting the code, I've noticed that the event listener for the "sidebarCollapse" element is removed after rendering the "without_sidebar" layout, and even when I call back the index controller method again it's not appearing anymore. Why is that? how should I render the default layout for my index page and the "without_sidebar" layout for the new page?

to go back again to the index page I'm using this a element inside the header of the `without_sidebar` layout:

`<a href="<%= yield(:forwarding_url) %>" class="btn text-white" type="button">`

where `forwarding_url = groups_path`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the first things I'd check:

First, is the application.js pack included in the without_sidebar layout? If not, add it.

Second, is turbolinks (or some other js rendering) causing #sidebarCollapse to render after jQuery attaches the event listener? If so, change your event handlers.

For turbolinks, instead of $(document).ready(...), try:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...
})
```

You can also write jQuery event listeners in a more resilient way:

```
$(document).on('#sidebarCollapse', 'click', function(event) {
...
})
```

Lastly, turbolinks makes linking between pages with different layouts rather tricky. You may just need to disable turbolinks in your link:

```
<%= link_to 'page', page_path, data: { turbolinks: false } %>
or
<a href="<%= yield(:forwarding_url) %>" class="btn text-white" type="button" data-turbolinks="false">
```